# Web application with separate database per account

Tags: database-design, multi-tenant

I am trying to create a .Net Core web application in which customers will create an account for their company and portal will create a separate database for that company. With that, every customer who signed in to our web application has their data separated from other customers. I was thinking to use multi-tenancy, but every article I saw is creating their databases before they deploy their application. But I need to create a database for a new customer on the run time so that when a new customer creates an account, their database will be created automatically.
My first question is, should I use a multi-tenant web application?
And secondly, how can I achieve creating a new database for new accounts at the run time?
Lastly, if I change something in my model, how can I publish it to all databases?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, databases can be created at run time. E.g. you could have your sign up app run an SP that only it has access to that creates a DB, however, simply adding a customerID to all tables and filtering all results by it would have a similar effect. You could create an EF wrapping layer that all apps use that requires a customerID in its constructor and exposes IQueryables already filtered by this ID.

Comment: Is there any article you know about creating db at run time with .net core? Preferably with EF core code first.

Comment: You can use EF to create the schema. However, if you are using separate DBs per customer, you will probably want to use different DB users access for them to and this isn't a part of code-first. I suggest you create a customer-DB-management database where you maintain a list of customers and the DBs they have access to and add a SP to this DB for creating the new DBs, then use code-first to create the schema in the new DB.